# Viewing Images Stored on a Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I  am new to setting up my own servers, I used heroku before now. So I built an app that involves taking snapshots of webpages, on a local Ubuntu machine. When I want to view the snapshots then I simply `open .`

Now I'm rebuilding this on an actual server and I need a way to view the (.png) files saved when the snapshot action is performed. I see the image details on the server but how do I view the image?

Comment: Is it a command line version or did you install a GUI?

Comment: Command line version, I'm trying`scp` but It doesn't seem to understand my local path `/Users/Me/Desktop`

Comment: What OS is your localhost running? if it's windows I suggest you use winscp

Comment: Also if you scp, execute this on your localhost if your screenshot is in your home folder: scp user@server.com:/home/youruser/screenshot.png .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no GUI on the server, you will have to copy them into a machine that does (ftp, sftp, rcp, scp, etc.) and open them.  If you have one, just open them.  You can also use the utility `fbi` (framebuffer image) to view the image in the console, but only if you have a frame-buffered console set up.

Comment: I'm trying `scp` now, however, I'm receiving this error: `/Users/Me/Desktop: No such file or directory` How much more info does `scp` need for the path?

Comment: `scp` cannot be used for browsing.  You provide the complete path including the server (local paths are assumed if the server is not included).  Eg: `scp user@server.domain:/full/path/to/file.ext destination/dir`.

Comment: `scp user@ip_address:screenshot.png /Users/Me/Desktop` this is what having trouble with. I am in the `dir` of the `screenshot.png` on the server where I'm executing the command, but there seems to be a problem with the second path.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by `scp` cannot be used for browsing

Comment: I think I resolved the path issue but I'm receiving a `permission denied` issue. I'll have to work my way through this. Thanks a lot Falcon!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GUI installed and you VNC into it, then you can just find your picture in the file manager and double click it to open it.

If you are on a CLI version, then I would suggest downloading (with sftp for example) that picture and viewing it on your local pc. If that is not an option for you, you will need to install an image viewer and n forward X from your ubuntu server to your local machine. After that you can open the picture with the viewer (read its manpage) and it will appear on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the image using:

- ascii art drawing using [aaview](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aview/) or in color with [cacaview](http://caca.zoy.org/)
- ssh X11 forwarding and a local Xserver and start remotely an image viewer
- VNC/NX
- transfer it and use a local viewer
- put it on a web server and browse that page. Start `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the same folder as the image, then browse your server on the port that python says is listening
- configure FTP, webdav or just sftp and use fuse to mount the remote folder on your workstation and use a local image viewer